# TCP Server/Client, is it important if server is accepting before client tries to connect?

Tags: c#, winforms, server, tcp

I am building a TCP Server/Client communication and for some reason it only works fine if the Server is accepting and then the client tries to connect. If I start the client before the server is accepting it doesn't do anything.

The server is not async (`clientHandle = serverHandle.Accept()`), maybe that's the problem, the client is (`s_ClientHandle.BeginnConnect(ipEndpoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), s_ClientHandle)`). It is not planned that the server get's data back, it is only meant to send it to the client.

Server:
I have a Windows Form, using a singleton class to call `StartServer()` and the server class
here is a simplefied version:

**I know this is a lot of code and the client is not included. The server code is only included because maybe it's better to understand my question**

If I use an async server (written down below), it is connecting well and like it should, but it never comes to sending the data because the server always listens (`while(true)` in `StartServer()`). Is there a way to add a safe thread? or something? So it can listen constantly but also send the data? Or is there a rule with `Accept` and `BeginAccept` that I don't know?

```
namespace Server
{
    public partial class NewForm : Form
    {
        string version = "null";

        public NewForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnTState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Singleton Single = Singleton.GetInstance();
            Single.SendMsg(txtMsg.text);
        }
    }
}
```

singleton class:

```
namespace Server{
    public sealed class Singleton
    {

        private static Singleton instance = null;

        public static Singleton GetInstance()            
        {
            if (instance == null)                        
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private Singleton()                               
        {
            Server.StartServer();
        }


        public void SendState(string msg)
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data = new byte[4];
            Array.Copy(enc.GetBytes(msg), 0, data, 0, 4);

            Server.SendToClients(data);

        }
   }
}
```

server

```
namespace Server
{
    internal class Server
    {
        private static Socket serverHandle;

        private static Socket clientHandle = null;

        private static ArrayList clientList = new ArrayList();



        public static void StartServer()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipep = null;
            ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 59999);  

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            serverHandle = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            serverHandle.Bind(ipep);
            serverHandle.Listen(20);

            clientHandle = serverHandle.Accept();
            clientList.Add(clientHandle);

        }


        public static void SendToClients(byte[] data)
        {
            ArrayList clients = GetClients();
            foreach (Socket client in clients)
            {
                client.Send(data, 0, data.Length, 0);

            }

        }

        private static ArrayList GetClients()
        {
            ArrayList returnValue = new ArrayList();

            lock (clientList)
            {
                foreach (Socket client in clientList)
                {
                    returnValue.Add(client);
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

async:

```
 public static void StartServer()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipep = null;
            try
            {
                ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 59999);

                serverHandle = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                serverHandle.Bind(ipep);
                serverHandle.Listen(61);


                while (true)
                {
                    allEventsDone.Reset();
                    serverHandle.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), serverHandle);

                    allEventsDone.WaitOne();
                }


            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {            }
        }

private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket server = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket clientHandle = server.EndAccept(ar);

                allEventsDone.Set();

                Read(clientHandle);     // reads data, calls readcallback etc
                lock (clientList)
                {
                    clientList.Add(client);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

client is async  (but it definetly works)

Comment: A client only tries a connection once and the ACCEPT method on server only works when client tries to make a connection. So server has to be started before client.  In some cases client code tries periodically to make a connection incases where a server may be offline.

Comment: The server has to bind and listen in order for the connection to succeed. The connection itself is usually established in the OS kernel and accept just gets the established connection from there. If no server is listening on the specific address, then the connection will fail.

Comment: @jdweng thank you, that's what I thought, should I add to the client that it tries to connect till it actually is connecting with a while loop? like `while( ! s_ClientHandle.Connected)` ?

Comment: That is not good idea because it constantly running using lots of processing power.

Comment: @jdweng then what is the correct approach? letting the thread sleep for a bit after every loop?

Comment: Yes or use Charlieface solution.

Answer (score 1):

The connection will only work if the server is listening.

If you want to handle multiple connections, it's much easier to do this with `async` and Tasks, and you should anyway convert your code to this more modern style.

- Make sure you pass a `CancellationToken` created from a `CancellationTokenSource`, you can then shutdown the server by cancelling it.
- Don't use a raw `Socket`, just use `TcpListener`.
- Don't use `127.0.0.1`, just use `IPAddress.Any`.
- `ArrayList` is deprecated, you should use `List<T>` instead. In this case you want `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead of using manual locking.

```cs
internal class VTrainSServer
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<TcpClient> clientList = new List<TcpClient>();

    public static async Task StartServer(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 59999));
        try
        {
            listener.Start(20);
            while(!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var client = await listener.AcceptAsync(cancel);
                clientList.Add(client);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { //
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var client in clientList)
                client.Dispose();

            if (listener.Active)
                listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    public static async Task SendToClients(byte[] data, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        foreach (var client in clients.ToArray())
        {
            cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var stream = client.GetStream();  // do not dispose or it will shut down the socket
            await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, cancel);
        }
    }

    private static List<TcpClient> GetClients()
    {
        return clientList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You would call this using a `CancellationToken` something like this

```cs
static CancellationTokenSource _cancel;

public async void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await VTrainSServer.StartServer(_cancel.Token);
}

public async void btnTState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await VTrainSServer.SendToClients(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtMsg.text), _cancel.Token);
}

public void btnStopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancel.Cancel()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however i am a bit confused. Why do I have to use `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`? And I dont fully understand cancellationToken. what do I give it when calling the function? I will read into it, but rn I don't know enough to ask actual questions :)

Comment: It's just much better than messing around with raw sockets, you don't have to bind or connect or anything, you just give it an endpoint and start the listener. See also new edit

Comment: This code is not working unfortunately for me. errors because of your use with `List<TcpClient>` and `foreach(Socket in ...)`, my server should not be startet seperately. As I showed in the code above I want it to start when sending data the first time is needed. But i loved to get an explanation of why you created your `StartServer()` methode like that. What in this code makes the server listen all the time, and is it possible to send the data then?

Comment: Fixed that error. You call it like this `await StartServer(YourCancellationToken);`. It calls `listener.Start` which initializes the underlying socket, then it loops `await listener.AcceptAsync` to accept as many clients as possible. Note that there are a large number of outstanding issues, not least that there is no way for the client to notify the server that it is disconnecting.

Comment: and is it possible to call `await StartServer(YourCancellationToken);` in the constructor of the singleton class? and it would still work to send something?

Comment: No you can't have an awaitable constructor, and I think it would not be correct design to open a netowrk socket in a constructor anyway. You should just call this from an `async void` function, in a button handler for example.